# Operation failed: "This request is not authorized to perform this operation." in Synapse with a Pyspark Notebook

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, azure-active-directory, azure-synapse

I try to execute the following command line:

```
mssparkutils.fs.ls("abfss://mycontainer@myadfs.dfs.core.windows.net/myfolder/")
```

I get the error:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:mssparkutils.fs.ls.
: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: Operation failed: "This request is not authorized to perform this operation.", 403, GET, https://myadfs.dfs.core.windows.net/mycontainer?upn=false&resource=filesystem&maxResults=5000&directory=myfolder&timeout=90&recursive=false, AuthorizationFailure, "This request is not authorized to perform this operation.
```

I followed the steps described in this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/security/how-to-grant-workspace-managed-identity-permissions#grant-the-managed-identity-permissions-to-adls-gen2-storage-account)

by granting access to me and my Synapse workspace the role of "Storage Blob Data Contributor" in the container or file system level:

[image]

[image]
Even that, I still get this persistent error. Am I missing other steps?

Answer (score 2):

I got the same kind of error in my environment. I just followed this [**official document**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/microsoft-spark-utilities?pivots=programming-language-python) and done the repro, now it's working fine for me. You can follow the below code it will solve your problem.

**Sample code:**

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
account_name = 'your_blob_name'
container_name = 'your_container_name'
relative_path = 'your_folder path'
linked_service_name = 'Your_linked_service_name'

sas_token = mssparkutils.credentials.getConnectionStringOrCreds(linked_service_name)
```

[image: Ref1]

**Access to Blob Storage**

```
path = 'wasbs://%s@%s.blob.core.windows.net/%s' % (container_name,account_name,relative_path)   
spark.conf.set('fs.azure.sas.%s.%s.blob.core.windows.net' % (container_name,account_name),sas_token)
  
print('Remote blob path: ' + path)
```

[image: Ref2]

**Sample output:**

[image: Ref3]

**Updated answer**

**Reference to configure Spark in pyspark notebook:**

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-synapse-analytics-blog/notebook-this-request-is-not-authorized-to-perform-this/ba-p/1712566

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer. I succeeded to get the token but it's still not working. I still get the same error.  For the Spark config in adls, is it correct: spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.auth.type.%s.dfs.core.windows.net" % (account_name), "SAS")
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.sas.token.provider.type.%s.dfs.core.windows.net" % (account_name), sas_token) ? I don't know why it works with Blob storage and not Data Lake Gen 2.

Comment: let me know if it solved your problem or not : )

Comment: Thanks a lot. You second link helped me to solve my problem.My problem comes from on how to configure Spark in pyspark notebook. I already granted myself the role of Storage Blob Data Contributor :)

Comment: You should raise your comment as an answer because that's this one that helped me to solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is that you have Storage Firewall running on the Storage Account containing your Data Lake/Blob Container.

As far as I can make out there is not way around this unless you have private networking enabled on your Synapse instance - in which case you can create a Managed Private Endpoint to enable a Spark to Storage network route.